# What is the Dialogflow entity for storing string responses?

Tags: string, dialogflow-es, entities

I am getting started with Dialogflow. I am creating a simple chat-bot for my API. The role of the Agent here is to help the user create a new enrollment directly from the chat window. It does this by prompting the user for necessary data to create a new enrollment and then performs the tasks at the back-end.
One of the things the Agent asks the user is to enter an enrollment code. The enrollment code can either be an integer or a string. Example enrollment code values - abcd, 1234, abc123, test 101, new test987.

I have looked at the existing system entities and the closest entity type that I have found was @sys.flight-numbers for storing alphanumeric data types. I do not know the implications of using that system entity for storing string data types and so I have decided to create one of my own. I created a custom developer entity '@code', by giving my entity a ton of example enrollment codes, and also checked the box 'allow automated expansions'.

I did give my agent a lot of training responses, both natural expressions and annotated expressions. However, when I try to give a new natural user utterance for my agent, it fails to pick it up. It only identifies the integers as @sys.number and I have to manually annotate the enrollment code to my custom entity '@code' that I have created.

Any suggestions/help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex pattern for your captured code as [shown here](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-regex-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js).
You can use `@sys.any` to capture the parameters from the user and in the webhook check using the regex. You may need to enable `slot-filing` for webhook to handle entity extraction.